# How do I stop the "which browser" window from popping up every time I try to open a new page in the stock browser?

Tags: stock-browser

My stock browser never used to have this problem until I downloaded the Puffin browser and the Photon browser today.  So, every time I type in a URL or open a new window in the stock browser I get the "select which browser" to use with the "always" and "once" button options.  I wanted it to stop popping up so I click "always" but after that I don't know how to proceed. Chrome doesn't seem to be affected. How do I fix this?

OS: 4.1.1
Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: Probably uninstalling the other browser would work, though you probably don't want to. It looks like the stock browser is asking for any of the applications to handle the tab, and then the android system isn't remembering the decision (Or the stock browser is making a unique request each time). Probably only way to fix is to remove other browser or to modify the stock browser in some way.

Comment: Could you clarify some things, please: Did you check the "always" checkbox, or did you just think about? If you did, what changed (or what didn't -- as you "don't know how to proceed")? Is this problem restricted to the stock browser only, and are you just talking about working inside that (i.e. clicking a link while in that browser, typing URLs into that browser's URL bar, etc.)?

Comment: @ Izzy: Yes, I click "always"  then it says go to "settings" but when I go to the "appications manager" to select "all" or whatever it says to do after pressing "always" I don't see what I 'm supposed to do exactly.  Yes, only with the stock browser; every time I click a link the popup shows up asking which browser I want to choose.